# Document set template (DocSet with pre-defined folders)

Tags: folder, document-set, template

I'm using document sets to store project for the team.
It has some meta data defined like start date, requester, owner and more stuff like that.
Now, within a document set, there should always be a couple of folders that are the same.
Think of folders like: Source files, For review, Final and Open project files.

Instead of having to create these folders by hand each time a new project (docset) is created, is there a way to "template" this so that a new docset has these folders by default?

Answer (score 0):

If this is SharePoint Online I would suggest to use PowerAutomate/Flow.

Every time a new item is added, check if the content type matches the Document Sets content type name/id and then create the folders.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response!
Yes, it is in sharepoint online.

I've trying around but can't seem to get it working.
I managed to create a flow that when a new item is created (a new document set), it creates a new folder (with a predefined name, which is good)) but it creates it in the root of the library, and not in the document set.
Also, when I create something else (document, folder) it still created that new folder in the root, and I have no idea how to check it.
I've been looking around on internet but can't puzzle it together :S

Comment: I got it. I start with an "**when item is created**" action. This has a **trigger condition** `@equals(triggerBody()?['{ContentType}']?['Name'], 'New Project')`. 
After that I initialize a variable to store the name of the project.
Then I finish with a **Create new folder** action where I use the variable in the folderpath, ending it with /desired_foldername.
Works like a charm!